# In Scala Cats Validated, how can combine ordered validations

Tags: scala, validation, scala-cats

In https://gist.github.com/satyagraha/897e427bfb5ed203e9d3054ac6705704 I have posted a Scala Cats validation scenario which seems reasonable, but I haven't found a very neat solution.

Essentially, there is a two-stage validation, where individual fields are validated, then a class constructor is called which may throw due to internal checks (in general this may not be under my control to change, hence the exception handling code). We wish to not to call the constructor if any field validation fails, but also combine any constructor failure into the final result. "Fail-fast" is definitely right here for the two-phase check.

This is a kind of `flatMap` problem, which the `cats.data.Validated` framework appears to handle via the `cats.data.Validated#andThen`operation. However I couldn't find a particularly neat solution to the problem as you can see in the code. There are quite a limited number of operations available on a `cats.syntax.CartesianBuilder` and is wasn't clear to me how to link it with the `andThen` operation.

Any ideas welcome! Note there is a Cats issue https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/1343 which possibly is related, not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a helper second-order function to wrap the exception-throwing ones:

```
def attempt[A, B](f: A => B): A => Validated[Message, B] = a => tryNonFatal(f(a))
```

Also, default companions of case classes extend the FunctionN trait, so there's no need to do `(User.apply _).tupled`, it can be shortened to `User.tupled` (on custom companions, you need to write `extends ((...) => ...))` but `apply` override will be autogenerated)

So we end up with that using `andThen`:

```
val valids = validateName(nameRepr) |@| validateDate(dateDepr)
val res: Validated[Message, User] = valids.tupled andThen attempt(User.tupled)
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution, and appears extensible to more general cases. Thanks!

Comment: In case it saves anybody some time... the symbol stands for the `product` method

Comment: @Lasf actually, the 2020 cats' way of writing it is to use a tuple. So, something like `(validateName(..), validateDate(..)).tupled andThen attempt(User.tupled)`

Answer (score 3):

For fail fast, chained validation it is easier to use `Either` than `Validated`. You can easily switch from `Either` to `Validated` or vice versa depending if you want error accumulation.

A possible solution to your problem would be to create a smart constructor for `User` which returns an `Either[Message, User]` and use this with `Validated[Message, (Name, Date)]`.

```
import cats.implicits._
import cats.data.Validated

def user(name: Name, date: Date): Either[Message, User] = 
  Either.catchNonFatal(User(name, date)).leftMap(Message.toMessage)

// error accumulation -> Validated
val valids: Validated[Message, (Name, Date)] = 
  (validateName(nameRepr) |@| validateDate(dateDepr)).tupled

// error short circuiting -> either
val userOrMessage: Either[Message, User] =
  valids.toEither.flatMap((user _).tupled)

// Either[Message,User] = Right(User(Name(joe),Date(now)))
```